# rTurk fails getting results from Amazon Mechanical Turk

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am experiencing a very strange problem. I am able to submit a HIT to Amazon Mechanical Turk correctly. I have a cron that keeps checking if there is any job ready to be reviewed. However, when a job is completed I am not receiving it but the HIT is disposed (what is done inside the function to review it). The strange thing is that this problem is not happening always, but quite often.

This is the code of the function to review the HITs:

```
def self.review_hits
hits = RTurk::Hit.all_reviewable
p "HITS"
p hits
puts "REVIEWABLE HITS: " + hits.count.to_s
hits_results = {}

unless hits.empty?
  hits.each do |hit|
    puts "IN EACH HIT"
    p hit
    results = []
    hit.expire!

    # Get results for each HIT assignment
    hit.assignments.each do |assignment|
      # Check if the assignmment has been submitted. It can be the case where the maximum waiting time
      # for the job to finish expired and there remain assignments that are not submitted
      if assignment.status == 'Submitted'
        p "STATUS 1"
        p assignment.status
        temp = {}
        temp[:worker_id] = assignment.worker_id
        temp[:answer] = assignment.answers
        p "STATUS 2"
        p assignment.status
        assignment.approve!
        results << temp
      end
    end

    begin
      hit.dispose!
    rescue
    end

    hits_results[hit.id] = {}
    hits_results[hit.id][:results] = results
  end

  # Let Rails know that there are new results
  AmazonTurkHit.store_results(hits_results) 
end
```

end

So the puts "REVIEWABLE HITS:" is 0 but the HIT is disposed. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

After some time becoming crazy about this I realised that the problem was very silly... I had two instances of the system running, one in production and one in staging but both with the same AWS account so sometimes the HIT was caught by the other system... :)